# React + Typescript. Generic Tuple

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I encountered a typing issue in TypeScript. I have an array of objects, each with its own `Generic` type. I haven't found a solution other than using `Tuples`.

Question: I've defined a type, but it doesn't automatically infer the type for the `item` parameter of the `render` function.

**My code**

React.js Component:

```js
import React from "react";

type ComponentItem<T> = {
  initialValue: T[];
  render: (item: T) => React.ReactElement;
};

type Props<T extends [...ComponentItem<any>[]]> = {
  items: [...T];
};

function Component<T extends [...ComponentItem<any>[]]>(props: Props<T>): React.ReactElement {
  return <div>Component</div>;
}
```

Input Data:

```
type Item1 = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};

type Item2 = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

const items_1: Item1[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Title 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Title 2",
  },
];

const items_2: Item2[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Name 2",
  },
];
```

Usage:

```js
<Component
    items={[
      {
        initialValue: items_1, // initialValue type is Item1. It's OK
        render: (item) => { // item type is any
          return (
            <>
              <h3>{item.title}</h3>
              <p>{item.description}</p>
            </>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        initialValue: items_2, // initialValue type is Item2. It's OK
        render: (item) => { // item type is any
          return <p>{item.name}</p>;
        },
      },
    ]}
/>
```

When I pass props to the `Component`, it infers the type for `initialValue`, but for `item`, it's always any. If I specify the type for item manually, it works, but I'd like it to infer the type based on the type passed to `initialValue`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do almost what you want it is to define the following function:

```js
const makeItem = <T>(item: ComponentItem<T>) => item;
```

It does nothing more than returning its argument unchanged, but because it is a generic function you will get nice inference.

Then when defining your items, simply wrap each item with that function:

```js
<Component
    items={[
      makeItem({
        initialValue: items_1, // initialValue type is Item1. It's OK
        render: (item) => { // item type is any
          return (
            <>
              <h3>{item.title}</h3>
              <p>{item.description}</p>
            </>
          );
        },
      }),
      makeItem({
        initialValue: items_2, // initialValue type is Item2. It's OK
        render: (item) => { // item type is any
          return <p>{item.name}</p>;
        },
      }) ,
    ]}
/>
```

You should now get the correct type for `item`, based on the type of `initialValue`, but the drawback is that you have to use this `makeItem` function.

Comment: It is very cool. Thanks for the answer, it can really help, but I would like to find a solution without additional functionality. I do not know if it is possible to do this only at the type level

Comment: I think it would require existential types which do not exist in Typescript, but I would be happy to be proven wrong.